# How to add ✓ check mark as a text in content of docdefination pdfmake

Tags: ionic4, pdfmake

I need to add checkmark(✓) in my pdf. Following is the code of my docdefination. I am creating pdf in Ionic 4

```
this.right='✓';


 content: [
          {//2
            text: this.right,
            absolutePosition: { x: 340, y: 100 },
            fontSize: 6
          }]
```

where `this.right` means checkmark symbol(✓ ).

Answer (score 1):

try adding content property. 
For example:

```
<style>
ul.tickedList li:before {
 content: '✓';
    color: #18ba9b;
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: 600;
}
</style>
```